# How to create function upgrade for class using PHP

Tags: php, upgrade

This is my code:

file Application.php:

```
class Application {

    private $upgrade;

    public function __construct($upgrade = null) {
        if (!is_null($upgrade) && ($upgrade instanceof ApplicationUpgrade)) {
            $this->setUpgrade($upgrade);

            if ($this->getUpgrade()->getVersion() > $this->getVersion()) {
                $this->getUpgrade()->upgrade();
            }
        }
    }

    public function getVersion() {
        return '1';
    }

    public function getUpgrade() {
        return $this->upgrade;
    }

    public function setUpgrade(ApplicationUpgrade $upgrade) {
        $this->upgrade = $upgrade;
    }

    public function sayHi($name) {
        echo 'Hi ' . $name . '!';
    }
}
```

file ApplicationUpgrade.php:

```
class ApplicationUpgrade {

    public function getVersion() {
        return '1.1';
    }

    public function upgrade() {
        //code upgrade here...
    }

    public function sayHi($name) {
        echo 'Hi ' . $name . ', Method has been upgraded!';
    }
}
```

now:

```
$app = new Application(new ApplicationUpgrade());
$app->sayHi('A');
```

i want before upgrade, sayHi return 'Hi A!' and after upgrade, sayHi return 'Hi A, Method has been upgraded!'.

Comment: What have you *tried* to accomplish this? We like to see **effort** in research and unsuccessful attempts, not just in throwing it at the community asking "How?"

Comment: Explain your question better please.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, but i think it's a little bad practice but anyway here you go

```
<?php
class Application {
    public function sayHi($name) {
       if($this->upgrade !== null) {
          $this->upgrade->sayHi($name);
       }
       else {
          echo 'Hi ' . $name . '!';
       }
    }
}
```

It's impossble to override methods from outside the class or by passing arguments

Another options is extending the Application class and override some of the methods
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

You should read the docs because it's a good starting point to learn the very basics of OOP

```
class Application {
  public function sayHi() {
    echo('hi version1');
  }
}

class ApplicationV2 extends Application {
  public function sayHi() {
    echo('hi version2');
  }
}

$app = new ApplicationV2();
$app->sayHi();
```

Further I wouldn't do this ever to manage different versions, and you should google arround for way better solutions and do some research

Comment: I will find a solution on google, because I don't want change class name. tks!

Answer (score 0):

**(if still stays the question then:)**
in 2022 ,in a indirect way now you can:

```
<?php


class _{


public static $f;
public static function customconstruct($n,$o){
    self::$f[$n]=$o;
}

public static function method($n,$p){
    return self::$f[$n]($p);
}

}


_::customconstruct('yep',function($param){echo 'yes '.$param.'<hr>';});

_::$f['yep']('`2022');// calling "the function" directly from the variable

_::method('yep','`2022');// the same calling by a custom method

?>
```